# automating vector math problem creation using csv data source

Tags: graphics, csv, pythontex

I'm a teacher, and I'm looking to automate some homework problem creation with vector algebra. I would like to use a csv file (which I can pre-process for input to tex) with the format:

"question...","answer prompt","hints","vector1","vector2","resultant"

"question...","answer prompt","hints","vector1","vector2","resultant"

"question...","answer prompt","hints","vector1","vector2","resultant"

...

and output a set of pages (or images?) like the below sample. I'm not really sure where to start, and I'm not even sure TeX is the right place to go, but it feels correct to me. Maybe a combination of python and TeX? Are there up to date libraries for doing this? Best practice TeX packages? TeX packages that are already set up to receive input from csv?
[image: sample output]

Comment: I used to create worksheets using a combination of C++ and LaTeX.  I lost interest when I could not find any other teachers who thought it was a worthwhile project.  See http://www.elfsoft2000.com/worksheets/index.htm

Comment: Could you add the CSV line that would result in the image you show?

Comment: "What is the magnitude of the resultant displacement vector for the given path?","\lvert\vec{R}\rvert=______","a^2+b^2=c^2;Remember,square root is the opposite of squaring a number","(8,10,0)","(2,5,0)","(10,15,0)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to process CSV is provided by these packages.

- datatool
- csvsimple
- xparse

The ability to set up a database for assignment questions is provided by these packages or classes

- exam (class)
- probsoln
- exercises

The advantage of keeping a CSV as you propose is that you can created it within a tool as simple as a text editor and as complex as a relational or UI-designed database. The disadvantage may be that you loose or struggle hard to establish the ability for figures such as you show to be dynamic based only on changing text inputs in a CSV file.

Here is a basic example with `datatool`. Put this in a folder. Add two .pdf image files named fig1.pdf and fig2.pdf. Compile the .tex file.

```
\documentclass{article}

% datatool does the database work
\usepackage{datatool}

% graphix does graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}

% short command to put a figure
\newcommand*{\putfig}[2][1]{%
    \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{#2}
    }
\newcommand*{\ifmissing}[2][]{\DTLifnull{#2}{#1}{#2}}

% the file contents
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{questions.csv}
question, answerline, hint1, hint2, figure
How much was it?, value here \rule{1cm}{1pt}, hint a, , \putfig{fig1}
How much is it now?, value here \rule{1cm}{1pt}, hint 1, hint 2
How much will it be later?, value here \rule{1cm}{1pt}, , ,\putfig[0.4]{fig2}
\end{filecontents*}

% load the database to the document
\DTLloaddb{problems}{questions.csv}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\DTLforeach{problems}{%
    \q=question, \a=answerline, \ha=hint1, \hb=hint2, \f=figure}
    {%
    % question
    \item \q
    
    % hints (if present)
    \ifmissing{\ha} \ifmissing{\hb}
    
    % figure (if present)
    \ifmissing[no figure b here]{\f}
    
    \a
    }

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll take a look at these, and see if I can create a minimal example. Thanks for the start

Comment: I've added a basic example for using `datatool`. I have also used `probsoln`, especially also to connect to a UI-level database application. The database stores just the content portions to problems, an export script in the database spits out the formatted latex file with just the problems, and the for-loop construction in the `problsoln` package pulls in the problems as a list (itemized or enumerated). `Probsoln` is designed for tex while `datatool` is designed for csv. Both are by the same author. The manuals for both are quite comprehensive.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm going to give this a try.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest a proccess.

1. Define the variables stored in the CSV
2. Create a Python script to produce the CSV. (Or JSON maybe?)
3. Create a working LaTeX example using the data of any line in your CSV. This example will be used as a template later.
4. Write a Python script to fill in the template with the data from the csv.
5. Write the finished text to a .tex file
   6  Run LaTeX using the script.

As a fellow teacher, I have done something like that some years ago, creating list of quadratic equations. I were very happy for my accomplishment,BUT in the end, how many of these (uncountable) examples are going to be serving during the school process? Is that kind of automation really needed? Is it your intention to print them on paper? Maybe a web app using HTML + CSS + JavaScript + MathJaxx would be more valuable for your students.

Comment: Feel free to contact me if you have further questions.

Comment: In terms of utility for my teaching the challenge comes in with differentiation. I'm basically creating assignments for EL 1,2,3, and native speakers + CP/Honors. I have all of these groups in the same section. Being able to generate these alternatives quickly is the goal. I don't think the system needs to be complex, but there are enough variations that it would simplify my work. Additionally, my EL 0 students I send content to the translators which is far simpler if I can send just the copy separate from the document. So for any given assignment, set of slides, etc, there can be 5 variations